# How to get reference of currently visible activity without passing it as parameter to other class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, back-stack

As the title says, I want to get the reference of currently visible activity or you can say activity which is at the top of `backstack` from a class, I don't want to send activity reference to that class, because I am using that class from many activities and if I do, I have to pass activity reference from every activity which is a long process.

I already have seen many answers which are typecasting context reference to activity but it is not working.

If anyone has the idea of how to do that in a short way, then please share.

Comment: If your intent is to get the Context, then you could just use the Application Context

Comment: No, i want to show dialog from that class

Comment: You can't really do this. There are some convuoluted ways of getting this information from the `ActivityManager`, but you shouldn't need to do this.

In a comment you say you want to show a `Dialog`. What component wants to show a `Dialog` in the "top `Activity`"? It looks to me like your architecture is broken. Please show some code or explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DavidWasser i need to show dialog for the failure of http calls, now what i did, i prepared a separate class which handles my http calls, so in that class i also handle some basic things like showing no Internet dialog, showing error dialog etc

In that class i need activity reference to show dialog, and this reference will be of that activity which is currently visible to user. I can send activity ref to that class but i am using that class in many activity, and that would be a long process if i do this, i need shorter one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way via we can do this, In your application class add: `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks`(this will listen to all activity lifecycle methods), like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static Activity currentActivity=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
                currentActivity=activity;
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
 if (MyApplication.currentActivity!=null){
             // your code here
        }
```

Don't forget to add your application class to manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        .../>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "long process".

Normally, if the `Activity` is delegating work to another class, it needs to pass itself as a reference so that the delegate knows how to call back the `Activity` to report progress, etc. This is standard Android stuff. `AsyncTask`  works like this (as an example).

However, if all you want to do is display a `Dialog`, then you can, instead, start an `Activity` that looks like a `Dialog`. This is also a pretty common Android solution. There are themes that you can apply to an `Activity` that make it look just like a `Dialog`.

Comment: By mean long process is, i have to send activity reference from every activity which is using that class. But the suggestion you gave in the second paragraph is the key.